# Python Program Loses Track of Time

Tags: python, time, serial-port

**[EDIT]**

I've added an incremental counter to the data, to see if I'm missing some data, I don't miss data. These are the times between packets in nanoseconds:

650255.8786692759 (Agrees with the oscilloscope)
500667.7866927593 (wrong)
491091.92954990215 (wrong)
484505.240704501 (wrong)
488062.3091976517 (wrong)
487157.1350293542 (wrong)
485264.33268101764 (wrong)

I have a Python Program that reads the serial port. And draws it on a Chart. Using Qt.

The data comes in every 300 microseconds (Confirmed with an Oscilloscope).

Problem is after the first run through of the worker Thread (traad()), it says the time is 100 microseconds between reads. (which is clearly wrong)

I just can't figure out what's wrong!

```
import serial
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
import numpy as np
import threading
import time
import re


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.lock = threading.Lock()

        self.Voltage = []
        self.tid = []
        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = []
        self.dataReady = False
        self.dataRead = True
        self.samples = 512
        self.x = threading.Thread(target=self.traad, args=(self.samples,))

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        self.x.start()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updater)
        self.timer.start(100)

    def traad(self, s):
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=576000, stopbits=2, bytesize=8)

        while True:
            while self.dataRead:
                self.dataRead = False
                self.lock.acquire()
                self.xdata = []
                self.ydata = []
                self.Voltage = []
                self.tid = []
                counter = 0
                self.lock.release()

                while counter < s:
                    if ser.read(1) == b'?':
                        data = ser.readline().strip()
                        stid = time.time_ns()
                        data = re.search(b"\\d+\\.\\d+", data)

                        if data:
                            self.lock.acquire()
                            self.Voltage.append(data.group(0))
                            self.tid.append(stid)
                            self.lock.release()
                            print(data.group(0))
                            counter += 1

                tot = self.get_samplerate(self.tid)
                xf, yf = self.CalcFft(self.Voltage, tot)

                self.lock.acquire()
                self.xdata = xf
                self.ydata = yf
                self.dataReady = True
                self.lock.release()


    def CalcFft(self, volt, deltatid):
        N = len(volt)
        T = deltatid / 1000000000

        yf = fft(volt)
        xf = fftfreq(N, T)[:N // 2]
        return xf, yf


    def get_samplerate(self, tider):
        total = []
        delta = 0
        test = 0
        for x in tider:
            total.append(x-test)
            test = x
        total.pop(0)

        for e in total:
            delta += e
        l = len(total)
        d = delta / l
        print(d)
        return d

    def updater(self):
        if self.dataReady:
            self.graphWidget.plot(self.xdata, 2.0 / self.samples * np.abs(self.ydata[0:self.samples // 2]))
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.dataReady = False
            self.dataRead = True
            self.lock.release()



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did you check if data processing time is shorter than 300microseconds?

Comment: I've added an incremental counter to the data, and you are completely correct, it misses some data. It had completely missed me, that the program would run too slow. Thank You.

Comment: I made a mistake, and added the counter twice, so i thought i was missing every other packet. It does receive all the data. It is just strange that the first run is correct, and all the other runs the time is wrong.

Comment: *"I have a Python Program that reads the serial port"* --  You neglect to describe the host system that you are using, but the *"serial port"* is probably an abstraction of the actual hardware that is provided by the OS.  Your Python program executes in userspace when the OS scheduler permits it to execute, i.e. it's not realtime and certainly not at interrupt level.  Your Python program "reads" from a system buffer, and not directly from hardware.